# Add to dataframe from the results in for loop? [index , value]

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, machine-learning, arraylist

I want to add in a pipeline 3 ML models and then I wish to pass them for cross validation with 10 splits. Now I want to store the result in a df with index as model name and score that is received from the model and cross validation.

```
model_names = ['Lasso', 'Ridge', 'KNeighbors Regression']
models = [Lasso(), Ridge() ,KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2) ]
iterr=0
scores =  [ ]
for index, model in enumerate(models):
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    score1 = model.score(x_test, y_test) 
    scores.append(score)
print(scores)
```

but this only gives the value.

Comment: If you want model_name, you can do model_names[index], to get the model_name. Do you want to append `score1`? Also why are you using `index`, you can just do `for model in models:`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sorry but can you please eloborate the answer. I didnt understand how to append model_name to score1

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a DataFrame from model_names and scores, how about:

```
pd.DataFrame(scores, index=model_names, columns=['score'])
```

resulting in:

```
                    score
Lasso                  12
Ridge                  12
KNeighbors Regression  12
```

Comment: More question to this question. If I want to perform a cross validation for 5 splits and I want to store the result in this form

Comment: Hi Murtaza, can you add some source data to your question so that I can see what we're talking about? I can find my way around pandas but not ML. Cheers, -Peter